# Using OWL as a mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, rdf, owl, ontology

I want to build a project with PHP where I can use OWL or RDF as my database (just like MySQL). That means that my main database will be developed in protege software. How do I do that? If it is not possible, please give me another idea. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to query OWL ontologies directly, you will most likely need to use Java, for example with the OWL API: https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi. As far as I know, there is no full fledged OWL 2 API in PHP. I believe Drupal (PHP-based) has a minimal support for RDF. You may want to consider looking at Triplestores (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore), since you plan on using the ontology as a database, which is much more efficient than simply adding the data to the ontology and run the reasoner.